# Yaml deserilization to POJO using Jackson

Tags: java, jackson, yaml, deserialization

How to deserialize Yaml to POJO when a key is dynamic? I have a Yaml file with this structure:

```
paths
  /user:
     get:
       summary: Example summary
       description: Some description
  /account
     post:
        summary: Another summary
        description: Another description
```

And I need to deserialize it to a Java Object:

```
public class PathsWrapper {
    private List<Path> paths;

}

public class Path {

    private String url;
    private List<Method> methods;

}

public class Method {

    private String method;
    private String summary;
    private String description;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map like so:

```
public class PathsWrapper {
    private List<Path> paths;
}

public class Path {
    private Map<String,List<Method>> url;
}

public class Method {
    private Map<String, MethodDescription> method;
}

public class MethodDescription {
    private String summary;
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know about this solution, but I need exactly the same POJO structure as I mentioned. This object will be proceeded further.